# Flyway H2 Database Creation Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**I can't figure out what is what is wrong based on the file structure of my project it is not following the correct file path[Pom.xml]**

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Wrong migration name format: V1.2_create_shipwreck.sql(It should look like this: V1.2__Description.sql)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.MigrationInfoHelper.extractVersionAndDescription(MigrationInfoHelper.java:54) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.scanForMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:133) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:99) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:49) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.collectMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:122) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.doFindAvailableMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:104) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:90) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:43) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.refresh(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:114) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.call(DbValidate.java:164) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.call(DbValidate.java:157) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:75) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.validate(DbValidate.java:157) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1280) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:71) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1176) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1168) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1650) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1168) ~[flyway-core-5.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Your migration file is missing one underscore. Rename `V1.2_create_shipwreck.sql` to `V1.2__create_shipwreck.sql` and it should work. See Flyway naming conventions at [flywaydb.org](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#naming-1)

Comment: Changed the naming conventions for it still giving the same error .   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected resolved migration not applied to database: 1.2

Comment: That's different error. You probably applied V1.0, V1.1, V1.3 was applied somehow meanwhile. Now by fixing underscores Flyway has found version V1.2, which wasn't applied before and it crashes.

Comment: What would be a fix for that then? cause it seems that it is seeingit now

Comment: Well thats out of scope this question and you should create new one.  If it's ok for you, you can simply drop database, if not search for: how to repair failed flyway migration.